# Unit Test debugging steps randomly through the code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2012

We've got a project which has recently been upgraded from being written under VS2010 (using .net Framework 3.5) to VS2012 (using .net Framework 4). We work with TFS, so older builds are available to work on.

When debugging the VS2010 versions of the build breakpointing the `<TestMethod()>` methods will work, stepping into and breakpointing on the called code works, and stepping through the code from start to finish works.

In the 2012 version, breakpoints only really work in the `<TestMethod()>` code. Once the code leaves the `<TestMethod()>` area, things get *odd*. Stepping into and through the code seems to simply step to random lines in the code. Values resolve strangely and the debugger seems to hop forward through the code largely at random. Once the debugger returns to the `<TestMethod()>` code area, things go back to normal, and the correct results are returned from the called functions even though the values shows during debugging were all strange.

I can't really think how to describe what's going on any better than that. I'm not in charge of building the software, and the people who are aren't aware of anything that they have changed that might have caused this issue.

Does any of this sound familiar enough to anyone that they can suggest what setting might have been changed to produce this behaviour, or what I need to set under .net 4 in order to get unit testing working again?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the source code that is being used by the debugger is different to the source code that has been used to compile the assembly you are debugging.

Comment: Isn't there usually a warning message when that happens?

Comment: @Frosty840: Usually, yes, but AFAIR, you can disable it.

Comment: Hrm. I've just gone and deliberately broken the test, debugged the test, gotten the weird, skippy-trippy code stepping, and the test failed. Unbroke the code, stepped through again, same weirdness, and the test passed. It definitely seems to be rebuilding in between every test. As far as I can tell, the code should be up to date.

Comment: @Frosty840: Did you break the test by changing the code of the test? Or the implementation that the test verifies?

Comment: Both. Separately and together (changed one, changed the other, reverted the first change, reverted the second, retesting each time). No joy. Stepping through is still trippy. :(

Comment: Please record a screencast. It's hard to help like this. (--> http://screencast.com / http://www.techsmith.com/download/jing/)